SOAP error "Envelope not defined", even though several sites say my XML is fine
I'm using soap to send a XML. However, at the site that validade my XML for the process, I've been getting the following message:
"Error line 2 column 116:It wasn't possible to find the declaration of the element  soapenv:Envelope"
I've used example documents from support, and scoured the internet trying to find how to fix this. My code is identical to the one from support and people on the internet, but still gives me the error. I've trying adding targetNamespace, and several iterations of what could it be, and I still haven't found an answer.
The government website from my country validade the XML before I can submit the code. In this case, every XML validator I tried told me everything was okay, EXCEPT, the government one.
This is my code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:nfse="http://nfse.abrasf.org.br"><soapenv:Body><nfse:recepcionarLoteRpsSincrono><xml><![CDATA[
<EnviarLoteRpsSincronoEnvio xmlns="http://www.abrasf.org.br/nfse.xsd">
  <LoteRps Id="1804204879" versao="2.04">


[...]
Can anybody help me, please?

That sample code is not valid XML. Please provide [mcve].
